# Interceptor method not called with interceptor binding

Tags: java, ejb, java-ee-6, interceptor

I'm using Java EE 6 & Jboss AS7.1 and try to use interceptor binding ([Example from jboss site](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/interceptors.html)).

I have an InterceptorBinding annotation:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface GeoRestrictedEquipment {
}
```

The interceptor:

```
@GeoRestrictedEquipment
@Interceptor
public class GeoRestrictedEquipmentInterceptor {

    @EJB EquipmentDao equipmenttDao;    
    @EJB SecurityService securityService;    

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object checker(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Integer id = (Integer) ctx.getParameters()[0];
        Equipment equipment = equipmenttDao.findById(id);
        GeoChecker.check(equipment.getSite(), securityService.getUser());

        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

And a bean:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@SecurityDomain(Realm.NAME)
@RolesAllowed({ Roles.REGISTERED })
public class PumpService implements PumpServiceLocal {

    @Override
    @GeoRestrictedEquipment
    public PumpInfos getPumpInfos(Integer pumpId) {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

But the interceptor is not called... What do I miss from the example ?

The interceptor is called when I write this:

```
@Override
@Interceptors({GeoRestrictedEquipmentInterceptor.class})
public PumpInfos getPumpInfos(Integer pumpId) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you enable your interceptor as described in the referenced example?

> By default, a bean archive has no enabled interceptors bound via
>   interceptor bindings. An interceptor must be explicitly enabled by
>   listing its class under the  element of the beans.xml
>   file of the bean archive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read the example too quickly, I thought that using annotations it was not mandatory to use the beans.xml but in fact it is...

Comment: This appears to be the case with JavaEE7 as well.

Answer (score 17):

According to the documentation there is another way rather than using beans.xml:

> You do not need to specify the interceptor in the beans.xml file when
>   you use the @Priority annotation.

```
@Logged
@Interceptor
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION)
public class LoggedInterceptor implements Serializable { ... }
```

And it works.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any priority value = Priority.Application is 2000 by default.

For example =

```
@Interceptor 
@Loggable 
@Priority(100)
public class FileLogger {}
```

Priority type:

- PLATFORM_BEFORE [0-999] - interceptors start at the first. They are started by the platform.
- LIBRARY_BEFORE [1000-1999] - by the libraries.
- APPLICATION [2000-2999]- by the application
- LIBRARY_AFTER,PLATFORM_AFTER [3000-4000]

You manage primary loading for interceptors.