# Using interceptor bindings from a jar

Tags: java, maven, annotations, cdi, weld

I have been searching for a while, but I can't found any information on how to achieve in Java EE to define custom annotations (interceptor bindings) to be able to be used in multiple maven modules without declaring it in every package where I would like to use it. It's basic interceptor where implementation only prints something into console.

An example is like `javax.ws.rs.Path` where this annotation can be used on multiple locations and everything what it needs to do is to import correct dependency. I cannot achieve same affect with my annotation.

I have created new maven module with the interceptor and binding annotation. I also have beans.xml file in META-INF folder to enable CDI. Then I add dependency of this module to other project, where I want to use this annotation. Problem is, that when I want to use this annotations, the implementation of annotation does not execute method which is annotated with `@AroundInvoke` annotation.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, because weld should start initializing bean implementation because CDI is enabled, but he don't, unless I put extra configuration for `<interceptor>` in beans.xml file where I want to use annotation.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What do you mean by *maven packages*?

Comment: You should've started by mentioning this is about weld :) So you have a `beans.xml` in your shared module, but you don't want one in your main (using) module, right?

Comment: sounds like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076586/interceptor-method-not-called-with-interceptor-binding/12081608#12081608

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by package you mean module;

You need to declare your annotation in its own maven module (possibly with other shared logic).  Then pull in that maven module as a dependency in your other modules.  That way you can use the annotation wherever you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. I tried creating new maven module and include it as dependency into another module, but this seems that does not work. When annotating method, implementation does not invoke ...

Comment: @Dahakka what do you mean by invoke? What should this annotation do, when, at by which technique.  Is this supposed to be an aspectJ annotation?

Comment: I will update my post with Update 2, to be more clear what I mean :)