# Wildfly 8.1 + EHCache + Annotations not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, caching, annotations, cdi, wildfly

I am building a Java EE application and want to use JSR107's @CacheResult annotation to "transparently" add some caching to my service layer. This is my first "full-featured" Java EE app, I usually work in Spring were annotation processing seems a lot easier ;)

So, here is my software stack:

- Wildfly 8.1
- List item
- EHCache 2.8
- EHCache-JCache
- JSR 107 Reference Implementation + annotation processing (https://github.com/jsr107/RI/tree/master/cache-annotations-ri)

... and this is the layout of my EAR:

- the root contains a few EJB/CDI bean jars
- /lib contains all required libraries
- one of the beans inside one of the root-level-jars contains a few methods annotated with @CacheResult, the parameters to the method are a String

My problem: no caching happens ;)

Concrete questions:

- has anyone here ever got the software stack I am using to successfully work together to perform caching?
- is there a way for me to get more debugging information on what is internally going on during interceptor processing? I tried various logger configurations and digged through the sources of the frameworks I am using but seem to miss the essential spot.

Thanks in advance

Sven

**Update**

It works if I explicitly add @Interceptors(CacheResultInterceptor.class) to the service bean. However, my own interceptors (within the same jar file) don't need to be declared that way, the respective interceptor binding type suffices. Is there a difference if I try to use interceptors that reside in an external jar?

Answer (score 3):

I found a related question with the correct answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081608/2290153

The relevant spec is http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.0/html/interceptors.html and the important part is section 9.4.

Specify CacheResultInterceptor (full qualified name) in beans.xml and that should work.